# Send arguments to tap UITap action : Swift

Tags: swift, arguments, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'd like to send arguments to UITapGestureRecognizer. I want to send a didRepond(Bool) to a "tapRespond" function. However, I have no idea how to do it. Could you tell me how to do it? If I should not use UITapGestureRecognizer, please
tell me another way. Thank you for your kindness.

```
didRespond = true
cell.respond.tag = indexPath.row //cell.respond is UILabel 
cell.respond.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self,action:"tapRespond:"))
```

// I updated as following.Outside of UITapGestureRecognizer, I switched the function.

```
didRespond = true
cell.respond.tag = indexPath.row //cell.respond is UILabel ]

if didRespond == false {
    cell.respond.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self,action:"willRespond:"))
} else {
    cell.respond.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self,action:"didRespond:"))
}
```

Comment: you just want a function... that tell you if they are touching the cell

Comment: Why are you send arguments to UITapGestureRecognizer?

Comment: Based on a value of didRespond, I'd like to change the function.